# Software for accessing documentations offline

Tags: gratis, osx, python, documentation-viewer

What are some nice gratis software for viewing programming documentation offline(preferably in Mac)?

An example documentation: [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

Answer (score 4):

For OSX there is Dash (https://kapeli.com/dash) free to try out, but costs $20 to remove delay when searching docs (last time I used it anyway). Really slick interface!

For Windows and Linux there is an open source "clone", a document viewer that is inspired by Dash. Zeal (https://github.com/zealdocs/zeal). It uses the same docsets as Dash, as long as it's not officially supported on OSX (https://github.com/zealdocs/zeal/issues/24). Haven't tried it out though.